# Selecting the maximum value from different list in python

Tags: python, dictionary, web-scraping

I have a list that looks like this, which I was able to get after scraping a website, but in this case these are different dimension of images from the website:

```
[72, 72]
[95, 96]
[13, 60]
[227, 973]
```

I have tried this but it is not giving me what I want:

```
    for items in height, width:
        dimension.append(items)
    print(max(dimension))
```

I want to be able to select the one with the maximum value which is:

```
[227, 973]
```

Comment: how do you define the maximum? the two values being multiplied together?

Comment: No, it is the output i got when i appended the height and width of each images to a list, so among that list i want to be able to select the image with the maximum dimension

Comment: The loop you use looks very strange to me - what is its goal?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I assume you have a two-dimensional list and are interested in finding the sublist, which contains the maximal element.

To find this, you can simply use pythons build in `max` function and provide a comparison function via the `key` parameter. The key parameter takes a function of which the result is used for comparison, so for example: `key=lambda sublist: max(sublist)`. In this case, you can even simply pass the `max()` function itself as `key`

**To sum it up, something like this should work for you:**

```
x = [[72, 72], [95, 96], [13, 60], [227, 973]]
 
max_pair = max(x, key=max)
print(max_pair)
```

**After the discussion with you**, I assume you get the dimension values in a for loop (and don't have them in a list at the beginning) and want to get the max at the end. I modified your code a bit and hope this works for you. It still uses the same idea as mentioned before:

```
dimensions = []
for something in something_else:
    image = get_image()
    height, width, _ = image.shape
    dimensions.append([height, width])
max_dimension = max(dimensions, key=max)
print(max_dimension)
```

Comment: This is exactly what i want to achieve, thak you @attalos

Comment: I'm happy to help :) Could you then mark the answer as correct please?

Comment: but don't know why it is returning int values cannot be iterated

Comment: could you rephrase that question please? I'm not sure what you mean

Comment: that is exactly what i want to achieve, i tried to enclose the above list in question into a list to containing all the list, but still no differences

Comment: What do you mean with "but still no differences".
Is the list x as used by me not the existing input you are working with?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/219274/discussion-between-nath-and-attalos).